# jquery-mobile collapsible accordion won't work when loaded in via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery-mobile page with a javascript function included that takes information from a JSON sheet and injects it into the page. I am taking information and formatting it in a Collapsible set (accordion) format and when the page is loaded the information appears on the page but just as text and not the desired format. I tested exactly what the js was printing out by hardcoding it into the div and when I do that it is formatted so its clearly something to do with the function. It is reading and printing out the information, just failing to recognise the collapsible format. Heres the function and html and I'd appreciate it if you could help me out:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script> 
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="Page1">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
  <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data- icon="back"> Back </a>
  <a href="info.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info"> Info </a>
  <h2>Septicaemia</h2>
 </div>

<div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Page1_Content">

<p class="infotext"><b>Clinical Condition:</b></p>

<div id="texts" data-role="collapsible-set">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function(){ 
  var info="";  
  var imp= "Json/empirical.json";
  $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {

   $.each(data.tcontent, function(i, item) {
    if(item.Name=='Septicaemia'){
     var search=item.Variations;
     $.each(search, function(j, subitem) {
        info += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d"> <h3>' + subitem.condition +'</h3> <p class="guidelinetext">' +  subitem.organisms + subitem.antimicrobial + subitem.alternative + subitem.comments + '</p> </div>';                        
    });
 }
    $("#texts").empty().append(info);
  });
 });
});

</script> 

</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
<h2>(c) Darragh O'Connor </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to _re-enhance_ collapsible-set. `$("#texts").empty().append(info).collapsibleset();`

Comment: doesn't he should call a refresh on the dynamic created collapsible via `$('#Page1').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();` ?

Comment: @Omar That worked. Thank you. Can you please explain why so I can get a better understanding of it? Is this just a jquery-mobile specific function?

Comment: dynamic content has to be enhanced by jqm after adding it to the sourcecode. jqm adds his own stuff after calling the refresh methods on the controls. this is done automatic on pageload, but has to be called manually on dynmic created content.

Comment: Is there a list of these enhancing functions for other formats apart from .collapsible()?

Comment: No. If you are adding dynamic content, just reenhance it and take a look at the jqm documentation for the correct syntax. Every control has its own refresh/reload methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[collapsible-set](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/collapsibleset/)** is a widget which has special functions to *enhance* it manually. When you add items dynamically, you need to call those functions manually as jQM can't *enhance* dyanmicaly added items by itself.

All elements are enhanced once jQM is initiate, after that you have do initiate dynamic elements manually.

```
$("#texts").empty().append(info).collapsibleset();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/A5Nbv/)**

Comment: I want to add popups within these collapsible blocks. Will I have to initialise them also? If so how?

Comment: @Darragh yes, any dynamic item should be initialized manually. I'll get you an example later on.

Comment: @Darragh I've updated with how to dynamically create a popup. If you need clarification, let me know.

Comment: thanks, this clears up quite a bit for me. However, I intend to link the popup to text I'm printing from the JSON function. For example info in your DEMO would be: 

'<div data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d"> <h3>' + data.name + '</h3> <p class="guidelinetext">''<a href="#pop3" data-rel="popup"> Expand</a> <div data-role="popup" id="pop3"> <p>' + data.val + '</p></div></p></div>';

Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Darragh this is also possible, but note that popup div can't be inside any element. It should go under `data-role=page` div. in other words, direct parent of popup div is page div.

Comment: is this only because its being created dynamically or in general? Because I have hard-coded a page where a popup div is inside a collapsible div. If creating it dynamically is the problem is there any other way in which I can get around this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48976/discussion-between-omar-and-darragh)